# How to solve warnings from yarn

Tags: react-native, yarnpkg

I did already solve:

```
warning " > react-native@0.54.3" has incorrect peer dependency "react@^16.3.0-alpha.1".
```

I just edit package.json dependencies:

```
...
"react": "^16.3.0-alpha.1",
...
```

and ran `yarn`.

But how can I solve following warnings:

```
warning "react-native > metro > @babel/plugin-check-constants@7.0.0-beta.38" has incorrect peer dependency "@babel/core@7.0.0-beta.38".
warning "jest-expo > babel-jest@22.4.3" has unmet peer dependency "babel-core@^6.0.0 || ^7.0.0-0".
```

my yarn version is 1.5.1
my whole package.json:

```
{
  "name": "#######",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "jest-expo": "^25.1.0",
    "react-native-scripts": "^1.11.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.2.0"
  },
  "main": "./node_modules/react-native-scripts/build/bin/crna-entry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native-scripts start",
    "eject": "react-native-scripts eject",
    "android": "react-native-scripts android",
    "ios": "react-native-scripts ios",
    "test": "node node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --watch"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^6.3.1",
    "exp": "^47.4.4",
    "expo": "^23.0.4",
    "react": "^16.3.0-alpha.1",
    "react-native": "^0.54.3",
    "react-navigation": "^1.5.8"
  }
}
```

Comment: what is your npm version? I upgraded to 5.6.0 and babel warning vanished

Comment: Now I am up to date with everything (created a new app and copied all files into it). But it would be nice to know anyway